# extract xml using a variable in awk

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I want search an XML file to extract specific XML block containing this string **58B338939C5B1970E1008000AC10E225_HCA_13**

I am able to do it via the following command:

```
  awk 'BEGIN{RS="<[/]?WorkResponseMessage>"} /58B338939C5B1970E1008000AC10E225_HCA_13/{print $0,"</WorkResponseMessage>"}' ag1.xml > ag2.xml
```

My query is I want to pass the search string in a variable from command line and use that variable to search, for example:

```
  awk 'BEGIN{RS="<[/]?WorkResponseMessage>"} /$m/{print $0,"</WorkResponseMessage>"}' ag1.xml > ag2.xml
```

Here 'm' is my variable. I am able to get the value inside 'm', but it doesn't seem to work with the awk command. I have tried using quotes("",'') for m as well and that doesn't work either. The **awk -v** option also doesn't work with this

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/120788/pass-shell-variable-as-a-pattern-to-awk

Comment: Use an XML/HTML parser (xmllint, xmlstarlet ...).

Comment: .. and where is your input `XML`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this -

```
m="58B338939C5B1970E1008000AC10E225_HCA_13"
echo $m
awk -v m="$m" 'BEGIN{RS="<[/]?WorkResponseMessage>"} $0 ~ m {print $0,"</WorkResponseMessage>"}' ag1.xml > ag2.xml
```